# ASP.NET MVC invalid initializer member declarator when trying to increment value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

As you can see on my codes in controller below, I'm trying to duplicate an existing row and assign a new value. I get an error

> invalid initializer member declarator

when I try to increment a value e.g `FuritureCount += 1`. How do I solve this problem? Or is there another alternatives?

Controller:

```
var temp = db.Furnitures.Find(id);

var duplicateRow = new Furniture()
{
    FurnitureName = temp.FurnitureName,
    FurniturePrice = temp.FurniturePrice,
    FurnitureSupplier = temp.FurnitureSupplier,
    FurnitureCount += 1 //this produce error
}

db.Furnitures.Add(duplicateRow);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You create a new instance of `Furniture`. Why are you trying to increment its `FuritureCount` which is `0` at this moment?

Comment: your code seems more related to entity framework than MVC. you should mention it in the tags and mention the version number. it'll help the right people to find your question

Comment: yes, it is 0 at this moment

Comment: So why don't you code `FuritureCount = 1`?

Comment: do you mean `FuritureCount = temp.FuritureCount + 1`?

Comment: It depends on what the logic requires.

Comment: @CodeFuller i cant directly assign it to `1` because everytime I submitted the value, it must increment value by 1 otherwise its forever assign it as 1

Comment: @NevilleNazerane let me try first

Comment: InsertOnSubmit() is from Linq2Sql?

Comment: but is that what you wanted? one more than whatever is the value of `temp`?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane i just wanted to add 1 to the field

Comment: so you wanted to add one to temp.FuritureCount right?

Comment: @HenkHolterman sorry its suppose to be `db.Furnitures.Add(duplicateRow)` `db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: @NevilleNazerane yes

Comment: That was a very curious typo then.

Comment: @HenkHolterman sorry

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I think this solved the problem... maybe for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with MVC. It has to do with C# syntax. You can't use the `+=` operator at this point, because you should be setting a new value to `FuritureCount`. The only valid operator here is `=`, followed by a valid value for this property.

Also, Although all tutorials show code like yours in controllers, this is not a good design. Controllers should be translating data for the view. Data access should be done in a lower layer, i.e. in a different class injected to the controller.